# Child elements repeat inside of FlipView

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a FlipView that has DataTemplate that contains a NotebookPageCanvas. NotebookPageCanvas derives from Canvas and contains an InkManager. I am dynamically adding child elements to this canvas, and I am finding that the children are repeated on other pages of the FlipView.

For instance, if I start with 10 items in my FlipView, when I dynamically add a Rectangle to the canvas at index 0, the rectangle will also be added to the canvas at index 3. Everything works fine with three items in my FlipView, but after that, I can't find a pattern to how the child controls will behave. Here is my FlipView XAML.

```
<FlipView
        x:Name="flipView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"

        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}" SelectionChanged="flipView_SelectionChanged" >

        <FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="FlipViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,137,0,0"/>
            </Style>
        </FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>


                <local:NotebookPageCanvas  x:Name="InkCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Canvas.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BackgroundColor}" />
                    </Canvas.Background>

                    <TextBlock Foreground="BlueViolet" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="100" Text="{Binding Title}" />

                </local:NotebookPageCanvas>


            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `FlipView` virtualization is recycling existing items when it needs to load more data. You would just need to wipe the content of your canvas before it gets associated with a new `DataContext`. One way might be to use a binding to populate the children of your canvas and always wipe existing contents before you add new.